# Iframe does not fully load in all IE versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to load an `iframe`, get an part of his content and delete the iframe.
My solution works on FF, Chrome but fails sometimes in all IE versions.

When I load an page in browser I see the its full content, but when I load exactly the same page in `iframe` there are missing elements from the page.

I've tried to add the `iframe` by hand from console and sometimes the page load all its content ,some times it doesn't.

Does anyone have a clue why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

i believe that not declaring DOCTYPE (in both the iframe source and the parent) can cause issues like that.
undeclared doctypes can cause the browser to revert to [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)

Comment: my documents, as i mention are exactly the same. And i have the HTML 4.01 doctype on both of them.

Comment: which elements are missing?